# How to use two Wordpress templates at once... or something similar?

Tags: php, javascript, wordpress, templates

I'm building a wordpress template with a lot of javascript, so I am also setting up a fallback version what requires different php in the index file of the template, and preferably, different header files.

The best way to do a fallback seems to be setting a javascript redirect on the "non-javascript site" to go to the "javascript version" of the site.

I am a bit confused on how the index.php file from the template folder trickles all the way down to the root directly. Yes, a understand php includes, but don't know how to jam a different file down the wordpress pipeline.

I was thinking I could do a redirect to mywebsite.com/index2.php but then I realized I didn't know how to get that to work.

Any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

It isn't the index.php that handles what template you use. Is a field in the database.

You would need to create a new theme that has both and switches them based on a session variable.

I am guessing this is nontrivial.